# onDraw method is not drawing

Tags: android

i am working on application in which my ondraw method is not working properly. I checked similar questions but i didnt get the what is the problem. This code drawing a square but not the correct size. It's so small. Also ı write a code for cells but they are not even working. I didnt get the where is the problem.

My class Code:

```
public SudokuBoard(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setWillNotDraw(false);
    setWillNotCacheDrawing(false);

    TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,R.styleable.SudokuBoard,0,0);

    try{
        boardColor = a.getInteger(R.styleable.SudokuBoard_boardColor,0);
    }
    finally {
        a.recycle();
    }
}


@Override
protected void onMeasure(int width, int height){
    super.onMeasure(getWidth(),getHeight());

    int dimension = Math.min(this.getMeasuredWidth(),this.getMeasuredHeight());
    cellSize = dimension/9;
    setMeasuredDimension(dimension,dimension);
}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){

    boardColorPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    boardColorPaint.setStrokeWidth(16);
    boardColorPaint.setColor(boardColor);
    boardColorPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight(),boardColorPaint);
    drawBoard(canvas);

}
private void drawThinLine(){
    boardColorPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    boardColorPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
    boardColorPaint.setColor(boardColor);

}
private void drawThickLine(){
    boardColorPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    boardColorPaint.setStrokeWidth(4);
    boardColorPaint.setColor(boardColor);
}

private void drawBoard(Canvas canvas){
    for(int c = 0;c<10;c++){
        if(c%3==0){
            drawThickLine();
        }
        else{
            drawThinLine();
        }
        canvas.drawLine(cellSize*c,0,cellSize*c,getWidth(),boardColorPaint);

    }
    for(int r = 0;r<10;r++){
        if(r%3==0){
            drawThickLine();
        }
        else{
            drawThinLine();
        }
        canvas.drawLine(0,cellSize*r,getWidth(),cellSize*r,boardColorPaint);

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't know if it can help, but be aware that when it comes to drawing on a canvas, you are taking in pixels, not in dp.

Comment: Can you be more specific? You said `This code drawing a square but not the correct size. It's so small.`. What would you like to draw? What is correct size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call `getMeasuredWidth()` or `getMeasuredHeight()` from within `onMeasure()`, those values aren't determined until `setMeasuredDimension()` is called.

Also you shouldn't call `super.onMeasure()`, your job in `onMeasure()` is to calculate the dimensions and call `setMeasuredDimension()`.

Assuming your SodukoBoard is set as `layout_width="match_parent"` and `layout_height="match_parent"`, this code should set your SodukoBoard width to a square using the lesser of the two dimensions:

```
void onMeasure (int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
 int dimension = Math.min(MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec), MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec));
 setMeasuredDimension (dimension, dimension);
}
```